# c# Checking Index of Loop + Break Results in IndexOutOfRange?

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, indexoutofrangeexception

So yes, it's a simple IndexOutOfRange exception--don't hate me.  BUT, what I'm doing about it *should* be working, but isn't.  I'm using C# in Unity.  I would appreciate any and all help!

In the code below, I need to access the next key in the list.  If no key is found after [i], then break from the loop.  Simple...?
For some reason, it's seemingly not doing the check.

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
{
    // if the number of keys is less than the hypothetical next index, then exit the loop
    if (keys.Count < i + 1)
        break;

    // I am getting the error for this line
    Key nextKey = keys[i + 1];
    // do something with nextKey...

 }
```

I'm sure someone will suggest just doing `keys.Count-1` in the for loop, but when I do that, other parts of my script don't work as expected.  There has to be another way, right?  Maybe I'm overlooking something simple.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: check the loop. You declare 'i' but then use 'k' in your evaluation

Comment: Could rephrase your if as `if (i + 1 >=  keys.Count) break;`

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `keys.Count` is 1 and `i` is 0? Desired outcome is unclear.

Comment: Why do you think it *"should be working"*? For what value of `i` is your logic failing? Can you see why?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Seems like you made a typo where you wrote `if (keys.Count < i + 1)` when you meant `if (keys.Count <= i + 1)`

Comment: @Ruzihm either that or actually for readabilty I would always write `if(i + 1 >= key.Count)` or simply `if(i == key.Count - 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your error is in this logic:

```
if (keys.Count < i + 1) break;
Key nextKey = keys[i + 1];
```

If we remember that arrays are zero-based, and that the largest index is 1 less then the length of the array, then it becomes clear.

Let's pretend `keys.Count == 10` and `i == 9`. Since `10` is not less than `9 + 1`, we don't hit the `break` line. But then we try to access the index `9 + 1`, which is out of range for the array.

---

To fix this, we need to check if there's another key available after the current key. Since the max index is `keys.Count - 1`, we can just add a `break` statement if `i` is greater than or equal to that value (as @derHugo metioned in the comments, `i` would never be greater than this value unless we modified it inside the loop):

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
{
    if (i >= keys.Count - 1) break;
    
    Key nextKey = keys[i + 1];

    // do something with nextKey...
}
```

Or we can adjust the original loop index to only go up to the second-to-last valid index value and we don't have to do any additional checks inside the loop. This only makes sense if you don't need to process the last item at all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Key nextKey = keys[i + 1];

    // do something with nextKey...
}
```

Comment: I think `if (i == keys.Count - 1) break;` is enough .. it will never be `>` anyway

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error in the last iteration because you are accessing `keys[i + 1]`.

I was about to suggest keys. `Count-1` but I see you have mentioned it and therefore, I will suggest doing an if instead of accessing the out of range index.

```
if (i + 1 >= keys.Count)
{
    continue; // or break.. Depends on your logic
}

Key nextKey = keys[i + 1];
// do something with nextKey...
```